# .htaccess rewrite rule not working as expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of articles that are clickable the href is : /article/article-name

I would like this to redirect using a htaccess file to /article/article.php?id = article name

and display article/article-name

My current htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/?$ ./article/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

However this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .htaccess in your `/article/` directory:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /article/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

My take

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ article/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```